# nginx config for two Laravel projects in different location

Tags: laravel, nginx

I'm trying to run two Laravel projects in a different location without using domain name here my config file.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;     
    server_name ip ;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location /project1 {
     root /var/www/project1/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
  location /project2 {
     root /var/project2/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)\$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

That returns 404 for both and from the error log return /(nginx root)/favicon.ico failed to open.

Comment: Are you using Laravel Forge?

Comment: no i don't use Laravel Forge

Comment: I think you need to define the "server" block level document root to point to `/var/www` and remove root directives from from "locatin" blocks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx serves multiple apps with two different locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985545/nginx-serves-multiple-apps-with-two-different-locations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using another port 
some thing like that

```
server {
listen 85 ;
listen [::]:85 ;
server_name ip:85 ;
root /var/www/html/projectfolder1;
}
server {
listen 90 ;
listen [::]:90 ;
server_name ip:90 ;
root /var/www/projectfolder2;
}
```

hope that help some one