# Multiple Laravel Applications Using Nginx - Windows

Tags: laravel, windows, nginx

I have two different laravel application on my server machine.

They are located at:

`D:/APPLICATION/application1`

and

`D:/APPLICATION/application2`

Below is my `nginx.conf` content:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;        

        location / {
        root "D:/APPLICATION/application1/public";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php = 404;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        }

    location ^~ /application2 {
        alias "D:/APPLICATION/application2/public";     
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

            location ~ \.php$ {
               try_files $uri /index.php = 404;
               fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }  



     
    }
```

If I browse `http://x.x.x.x/`, my first laravel web application comes out perfectly.

But if I browse `http://x.x.x.x/application2` I am having `No input file specified.`

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: better use https://laragon.org/ for development

Comment: for two url i use 1 config file in nginx not in same file as nginx listion for specific port and server name

Comment: so u want dynamic.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For windows use `fastcgi_pass` as `127.0.0.1:9000` instead of unix socket.

Please make sure your php cgi is running. If not, you can start it by

```
1. Open command prompt
2. Go to path of php-cgi file. (e.g. C:\php-7.3.11, here you'll find fast-cgi.exe).
2. php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Nginx configuration with rewrite module.

```
# Nginx.conf
# App 1(Path: D:/APPLICATION/application1, Url: http://localhost)
# App 2(Path: D:/APPLICATION/application2, Url: http://localhost/application2)
server {
    # Listing port and host address
    # If 443, make sure to include ssl configuration for the same.
    listen 80; 
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name localhost;

    # Default index pages
    index index.php;

    # Root for / project
    root "D:/APPLICATION/application1/public";

    # Handle main root / project
    location / {
        #deny all;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Handle application2 project
    location /application2 {
        # Root for this project
        root "D:/APPLICATION/application2/public";

        # Rewrite $uri=/application2/xyz back to just $uri=/xyz
        rewrite ^/application2/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        # Try to send static file at $url or $uri/
        # Else try /index.php (which will hit location ~\.php$ below)
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Handle all locations *.php files (which will always be just /index.php)
    # via factcgi PHP-FPM unix socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # We don't want to pass /application2/xyz to PHP-FPM, we want just /xyz to pass to fastcgi REQUESTE_URI below. 
        # So laravel route('/xyz') responds to /application2/xyz as you would expect.
        set $newurl $request_uri;
        if ($newurl ~ ^/application2(.*)$) {
                set $newurl $1;
                root "D:/APPLICATION/application2/public";
        }

        # Pass all PHP files to fastcgi php fpm unix socket
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Use php fastcgi rather than php fpm sock
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000; 
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # Here we are telling php fpm to use updated route that we've created to properly
        # response to laravel routes.
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $newurl;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # Deny .ht* access
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Note: When we're using session based laravel setup, all the route generator functions(`url(), route()`) use hostname `localhost` as root url not `localhost/application2`. To resolve this issue please do following changes in laravel app.

1. Define `APP_URL` in `.env` file as `APP_URL="localhost/application2"`
2. Go to `RouteServiceProvider` which is located at `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider` and force laravel to use APP_URL as root url for your app.

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    // Add following lines to force laravel to use APP_URL as root url for the app.
    $strBaseURL = $this->app['url'];
    $strBaseURL->forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
}
```

**Update**: Make sure to run `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache` command to load the updated value of `APP_URL`.

For Linux System : [Nginx: Serve multiple Laravel apps with same url but two different sub locations in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985545/nginx-serve-multiple-laravel-apps-with-same-url-but-two-different-sub-locations/63882428#63882428)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I am running on Windows machine.

Comment: thank you very much, I will give you the `+100` reward on the other question should we make this work out. thank you very much

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question, but I am using it for my laravel application. but i installed nginx manually.

Comment: i installed it manually, no 3rd party. i got it from http://nginx.org/en/download.html

Comment: please let me know if you have already updated your answer. thank you very much!

Comment: i can access the `http://x.x.x.x/application2/login` manually but i cannot login. it always redirect me to `http://x.x.x.x/login`. also, if i browse `http://x.x.x.x/application2` it should go to `http://x.x.x.x/application2/login` automatically because i have a middleware in place for that app. something small must be missing here, but we are so close.

Comment: i also think that the images on my login page at my `/application2` that were not showing is related to the issue.

Comment: @kapitan, issue was not with nginx setup but due to behavior of `url()` function in laravel itself. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: SO said that i can reward the `+100` rep from the other question in 3hours.will give it by then.thanks again.