# Laravel url method post not point to project folder?

Tags: laravel, url, post, routes, localhost

why my laravel url not working when method is post
example the url api must be : **http://localhost/PROJECTNAME/api/loginWeb**

but when i click post button it always direct to **http://localhost/api/loginWeb**

but when method is **get** this okay. i use xampp

here is my htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: in `.env` set `APP_URL=`

Comment: yes, already set APP_URL=http://localhost or APP_URL=http://localhost/PROJECTFOLDER but still not working

Comment: how you are testing that url is not working?

Comment: i am using api for login , so i just check the inspect element, the url always direct to localhost/api instead localhost/projectfolder/api

Comment: you are using vuejs .? or ajax

Answer (score 0):

When we're using session based laravel setup, all the route generator functions(`url(), route()`) use hostname `http://localhost` as root url, not `http://localhost/PROJECTNAME`. To resolve this issue please do following changes in laravel app.

- Define APP_URL in .env file as `APP_URL="http://localhost/PROJECTNAME"`
- Go to `RouteServiceProvider` which is located at `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider` and force laravel to use `APP_URL` as root url for your app.

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    // Add following lines to force laravel to use APP_URL as root url for the app.
    $strBaseURL = $this->app['url'];
    $strBaseURL->forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
}
```

Same issue occurred to me when I used same domain and a suburl to identify different projects.

- Linux: [Nginx serves multiple apps with two different locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985545/nginx-serves-multiple-apps-with-two-different-locations)
- Windows: [Multiple Laravel Applications Using Nginx - Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880881/multiple-laravel-applications-using-nginx-windows)