# Nginx subdirectory on laravel using docker gives 404

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, fastcgi

I have a nginx container which has a upstream to my laravel containers , with the below config file , I am trying to add a location named `cms` which should use my laravel upstream servers then. But now I'm getting 404 , file not found error . I have tried almost every solution on the internet but no achievement.

**Nignx.conf**

```
            location ^~ /cms/ {
                root /var/www/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @cms;              

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                        fastcgi_pass   redirect;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
}
 location @cms{
                       rewrite /cms/(.*)$ /cms/index.php?/$1 last;
                       #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                }
```

**PHP-FPM log**

```
172.10.9.91 -  17/Sep/2020:14:29:59 +0000 "GET /cms/index.php" 404

172.10.9.91 -  17/Sep/2020:14:30:05 +0000 "GET /cms/index.php" 404

172.10.9.91 -  17/Sep/2020:14:30:20 +0000 "GET /cms/index.php" 404

172.10.9.91 -  17/Sep/2020:14:30:30 +0000 "GET /cms/index.php" 404
```

When I try to change the above config file by removing `/cms/index.php?/1$`, It seems Nginx does not use the upstream server and the code gives 404 on my current main domain.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985545/nginx-serves-multiple-apps-with-two-different-locations

Comment: I tried this way but it seems my request does not gets resolved to the upstream server , I get 404 not found on my current server.

Comment: did you check `RouteServiceProvider` changes? you need to make sure you do `php artisan config:clear` as there are changes in `APP_URL`

Comment: Yes , but again the NGINX is using the current upstream , is there any misconfiguration with my upstream config above?

Comment: It seems when the nginx redirects the url , it goes to the / location and renders via current / location

Comment: can you confirm, I see missing or misplaced `}` for `location ^~ /cms/ {`. It should be closed before php location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221645/discussion-between-jitendra-yadav-and-alimahdavi).