# NGINX alias/root or rewrite for a link loading from a different directory

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, alias, root

I've searched all over stackoverflow and can not find something that matches this yet, hopefully it's an easy one. What I want is set out below;

http://mylink.com should be loaded from /var/www/
http://mylink.com/l/random should be loaded from /test/random (word "random" is a random string of characters)

I have the below;

```
server {
        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name mylink.com www.mylink.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # Listing page (multiple files)
        location /l/ {
                root /test;
        }

////extra lines with php etc below
}
```

I have also tried with `location ^~ /l/(.*)` and then using the alias or root with the `$1` path, but cannot find the right combination to get it to work, normally returning a 404.

Basically by going without the "l" it should load the default `/var/www/` and with the "l" I want it to load the index.php from "/test/*" (* being what is after the "l" e.g. `mylink.com/l/customlink` -> `/test/customlink/index.php`

Any help would be appreciated, hopefully it's a simple thing I have wrong and I hope it makes sense!

Comment: Does [Nginx serves multiple apps with two different locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985545/nginx-serves-multiple-apps-with-two-different-locations/63882428#63882428) answer your question?

Comment: @JitendraYadav Still seem to be getting 404 by using the link you provided, will show the config, but I don't think that works the same

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ialexpw/4ba39755163fecd90bdb399d7061e49f - using this I cannot see any folders under /plug/other/* by going to the url /l/* even though I know those exist.

Comment: @JitendraYadav the root for the folder is /plug/other, the main root is /var/www/plug (the first is not under /var/www)

Comment: i see you're trying to access `php` file but you've not updated the php section from that link. As you know `php fast cgi` is an independent service and we need to tell it also for which path to look. See the `php` section from that link too

Comment: That was it, thank you! Didn't realise I needed that bit also, complete life saver!

Comment: dont' forget to upvote, if it works for you.