# Laravel redirect() helper doesn't work after overrided

Tags: php, laravel, architecture

I have some projects that need to deploy in same subdomain e.g :

- mainproject.domain.com
- mainproject.domain.com/secondproject

I've googling and found this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/a/63882428/12392547, his solution using `forceRootUrl` to change base url didn't works properly on my project.

So my approach to solve this issue is try to override the `route` method because my project using named routing `route('xx.yy.zz')` and I was tried to implement this way https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/override-functions-in-supporthelpersphp?page=1&replyId=188043 and override `route` method on my own helper and IT WORKS !

below is my code to override route method :

```php
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    $appUrl = "https://".getHostFull()->domain; // in my case: http://mainproject.com
    $appUrlSuffix = env('APP_URL_SUFFIX', '/2021'); // in my case: subdirectory

    if ((bool)env('IS_MAIN')) {
        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }
    // Additional check, do the workaround only when a suffix is present and only when urls are absolute
    if ($appUrlSuffix && $absolute) {
        // Add the relative path to the app root url
        $relativePath = app('url')->route($name, $parameters, false);
        $url = "$appUrl$appUrlSuffix$relativePath";
    } else {
        // This is the default behavior of route() you can find in laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php
        $url = app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }

    return $url;
}
```

but sadly, there still an issue with syntax `redirect()->route()` and `redirect()->back()` so Iam using same approach like before but there is an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::route

I believe there is something wrong with my code because I just copied it from `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`

```php
function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    $appUrlSuffix = env('APP_URL_SUFFIX', '/2021'); // in my case: subdirectory

    if ((bool)env('IS_MAIN')) {
        return redirect()->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
    }

    if (is_null($to)) {
        return app('redirect');
    }

    return app('redirect')->to($to, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

Anyone can fix my code or you guys might have others approach to solve my case ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/wNisNRu1aaE  i think look after this tutorial which helps you to solve your issue in better way.......

Comment: @SaravanaSai, I've watch it, but actually in my case is in subdomain .. so the main project looks like : `x.mainproject.com` so if I use that solution, isn't it would be `secondproject.x.mainproject.com` ?

Comment: can you share me the code throught the github. above video i have recommended you redirecting to subdomine ....i think i cant get a question properly ..

Comment: personally I'd look for another solution like using a subdomain. But thats not the answer youre looking for

Comment: @Flame, Yes.. I don't wanna use subdomain because my projects deployed on subdomain already , my client don't wanna use `sub sub domain`