# Nginx with multiple Laravel applications and AWS gateway

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have 3 Laravel applications on EC2 instance under /var/www/html as:

- /var/www/html/app1
- /var/www/html/app2
- /var/www/html/app3

The EC2 instance (ubuntu server) doesn't have a public IP and can be accessed only with

1- API Gateway

2- Its private IP when I use a VPN connection.

I created 3 API Gateway routes such as:

- https://MyGatewayID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com  (for app1)
- https://MyGatewayID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app2
- https://MyGatewayID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app3

**All of them use port 80**

My current Nginx configuration for server is as following

```
server {
       listen 80;
       root /var/www/html/app1/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name _;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        location / {
               # First attempt to serve request as file, then
               # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }



        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
                           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                           include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

This seems to work as expected when I use the private ip of the server (when the VPN connection is on) and the routes will be resolved as 10.0.143.153/login or 10.0.143.153/users.

However, when I use "https://MyGatewayID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" it opens just the index page but then if I try to press "login" inside the application it will try to navigate to https://MyGatewayID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/login which wont work.

I am not sure how to go with more than one application, and it seems like all the solutions I tried are using one application or they are using the server_name variable which I believe doesn't matter in my case (since the server doesn't have public ip).

I tried this solution

[Nginx: Serve multiple Laravel apps with same url but two different sub locations in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985545/nginx-serve-multiple-laravel-apps-with-same-url-but-two-different-sub-locations)

It seems to be working with private-ip/app2 private-ip/app3 when the VPN is on. However, I wasn't able to make it work with the API Gateway. Also, this solution requires some changes in the application code, and I am wondering if I can do it only with nginx config.

I am totally new to Nginx and AWS API gateway, so please excuse my lack of knowledge, and guide me to the right direction if you think I am missing the point.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/838082/nginx-two-locations-inside-same-server might be helpful

Comment: server_name in my case doesn't matter since the EC2 instance doesn't have a public IP and can't be accessed directly without the API gateway

Comment: no I was talking about different `root` within each `location`

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63882428/3382285

The AWS API gateway route needs to match the application location in Nginx configuration route and needs to integrate using the same port.

for example if the location is /app2

```
        location /app2 {
               # First attempt to serve request as file, then
               # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
```

then the AWS gateway would look like
https://MyGatewayID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app2

And to make all the app routes functional I used a wild card route such as:

/app2/{api+}

I am not 100% sure what is the performance impact in using such a solution since all applications are in one nginx server block and are using the same port, but this would be another question.